# When parenting an object to a bone the location of the object changes. Why?

Tags: modeling, animation

I have a problem parenting objects to bones. I've been struggling with this for sometime today now. The issue is that the moment I try to parent an object it's location and rotation are altered. So far I've been unable to find a solution online. Images and project file below.
I did apply transformations for all objects.

File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c2156f94ykvakm/Lamp.blend?dl=0

Process:
Select object in Object mode
Shift select armature
Select bone in pose mode
CTRL+P -> Bone

Before and after pictures for first two objects + bones:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: I found a workaround, after parenting there's a box labeled 'keep transform'. Strange enough I can toggle that on and off and it resets the transformation. Doesn't matter if I turn it on or off actually.

This is probably not the solution I'm looking for, although it works for now. Would still really appreciate any advice!

Comment: I don't see any object in your file(???)

Comment: I just checked and the file works on my computer. It's created in 2.8, don't know if that's relevant?

Comment: oh ok I opened in 2.79  ;)

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar enough with 2.8